# How to resolve Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'iconTint' in package 'android'?

Tags: android

I am getting error on `android:iconTint="@android:color/white` in this part of code:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Menu" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="Cart" />
```

I am getting errors for all these items.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

sample code ..

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:title="Menu" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:title="Cart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"
```

then:

```
app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
```

instead of:

```
android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
```